# Microsoft EWS with Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to build an app using Apache Cordova that involves using Microsoft EWS to access my Outlook account.

I currently have a working app using MVC but I cannot add similar references to the Cordova project in order for me to make similar calls to EWS. Are there any javascript API's or anything that I can add to be able to gain access to the functions I need?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your question about JavaScript api availability with EWS, the answer is NO, there is no official library available. I have published a port of official ews-managed-api from c# to JavaScript on npm named `ews-javascript-api` for nodejs community, it can be modified to used with cordova (MIT license).

If you can be more specific to what exactly you want to achieve in JavaScript, I can provide code sample.

Comment: I recently did the implement cordova/ionic/electron specific implementation for this library. take a look at [ews-js-api-browser](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-js-api-browser) which is based on multiple requests I received like this one - https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api/issues/190