# Cordova with EWS

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, soap, exchangewebservices

The communication with the Exchange server is going with SOAP requests.
When I try to run this code on the mobile device I get a status code of "0".

Any help is appriciated.

Code:

```js
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        username:'username',
        password: 'password',
        url: 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx',
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapRequest,       
        success: function(data)
        {
            hyper.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            hyper.log('error status: ' + jqXHR.status + ' errorTrown: '+ thrownError);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Connecting from Cordova to EWS with jQuery did not work out for me. But i found a work arround wich might be usefull for some other people.
As an alternative I build a PHP webservice that handled al the communication with EWS.I didn't use the EWS-php class.
Cordova then called the webservice via jQuery.

I am now able to get and adjust calender events etc.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152138/5884960 I recently did modify the original library to work with cordova. new npm package is [`ews-js-api-browser`](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-js-api-browser)